# Induction proof on natural numbers

Tags: induction

I am trying to prove the following using **induction**, and kind of stuck. I used a computer to validate this sentence. Using $n = 1$ gave the correct result. I assumed that this is true for some $n = k$, but how do I prove for $n = k+1$. Should logarithms be used?

$$2\leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\leq 3$$

I've seen similar solutions, but none with induction, I need a solution using the natural numbers, without limits and calculus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bounding Euler's e by showing $2 \leq (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n &lt; 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425981/bounding-eulers-e-by-showing-2-leq-1-frac1nn-3) **or** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980483/2-1-frac1nn-3-for-all-n-2 **or** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254335/prove-that-5-2-e-3/254339#254339 **or Bernoulli's inequality** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality